# Why i should choose SonarQube over tools like ReSharper, Fortify etc. and over code analyzing features that Microsoft provides?

Tags: sonarqube, resharper, fortify

Want to get a clear thought about why SonarQube should be chosen for code analysis, code review than the tools like ReSharper, Fortify etc. and why it is better than the code analysis features that Microsoft provides?

Comment: Better based on what criteria? Why do you even assume it's better, even among the free Roslyn analyzers like Roslynator?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to understand the purporse of these tools. Sonarqube are focused in code quality, Fortify do scans for code vulnerabilities. For CI/CD environments, it's quite common two tools running on each pipiline deployment, because those analysis are different.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube won't be necessary "better" then any other code analysis or code review tool. There are tons of tools like SonarQube out there that could do the job for you. The most important things to hold in mind are:

1. What are your needs according to such a tool?
2. Are there other constraints, such as demands for the employer you are working for?

This does not take away that SonarQube does a good job in what it is offering, especially the part where you can manage your own rules and profiles.

Also see:
https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/6daacw/sonarqube_vs_visual_studio_code_analysis/

Comment: mainly the need is that such a tool should be free to use in production

Comment: @akay so you want free, not better. That's not what you asked. Such a question is out of scope for SO anyway. Even SonarQube isn't free beyond its Community version. There are a *lot* of free Roslyn Analyzers in the VS marketplace but none of them will be as fast or comprehensive as Resharper